# How to use Audit.EntityFramework.Identity for .Net 6

Tags: asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, audit.net, audit.net.sqlserver

Identity in .Net 6 using razor pages. I want to audit ASP.NET Identity entities using Audit.EntityFramework.Identity. But I don't see any document.

I changed my ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : AuditIdentityDbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new AuditSaveChangesInterceptor());
    }
}
```

I don't see anything write to my Event table.

Comment: Are you [configuring a Data Provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#data-providers)? If not, the events are saved by default on the application directory as `.json` files. Also check [EF DataProvider docs](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#entity-framework-data-provider)

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out
before I put:

```
Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
                .ForContext<SSAreaDbContext>(_ => _
                    .AuditEventType("EF:{context}"))
                .UseOptOut();
```

SSAreaDbContext not include ApplicationDbContext

Now:

```
Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
                .ForAnyContext(x => x.IncludeEntityObjects(true)
                .AuditEventType("{context}:{database}"))
                .UseOptOut();
```

Everything is working now.